# Archive and unarchive a custom class(have a property as object array),always failed

Tags: swift, archive

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

when unarchive app crashes and i get this message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 
'*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (_TtCC11ArchiveTest8dogHouse3dog) 
for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked'
```

What does it means?
Anyone helps?Thanks in advance.

Now,I recognize the Terminating because other codes,like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq81u.jpg)

if I try:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jROW.jpg)
it's well done,buy why?code write in the viewDidLoad do anything else?which method linked the class?

I have a class:

```
let ModelPath = "Model.plist".cacheDir()

class dogHouse: NSObject , NSCoding{

 var dogs:[Dog]?

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    dogs = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dogs") as? [Dog]
    super.init()
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    if dogs != nil{
        aCoder.encode(dogs, forKey: "dogs")
    }

}

class Dog: NSObject , NSCoding {

    var name : String?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String?
        super.init()
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if name != nil{
            aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        }

    }

    //ArchiveModels
    func saveModel() -> Bool{
     return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self, toFile: ICModelPath)
    }

    //UnArchiveModels
    class func loadArchiver() -> [Dog]?{
      let obj = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: ICModelPath)
      if obj != nil {
         print(obj.debugDescription)
         let model = obj as? dogHouse
         return model?.dogs
      }
     return nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed a parameter in the `init` function?

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    dogs = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "dogs") as? [Dog]
    super.init(aDecoder) //HERE
}
```